# Change bean class name at runtime

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

we have bean defined in one project as below:

```
<bean class="a.b.c.d.classA" id="classA">
    <property name="prop1" ref="ref1"/>
</bean>
```

We are importing this configuration in another project and want to overwrite bean definition during patch installation.
So, here we need change class but other details will keep as it is (no change in bean id).

```
<bean class="a.b.c.d.classB" id="classA">
    <property name="prop1" ref="ref1"/>
</bean>
```

With patch install XML file , we thought to do it using ant call like this:

```
<xmltask source="beans.xml" dest="beans.xml">
    <remove path="/beans/bean[@id='classA']/@class"/>
</xmltask>

<antcall target="abcd">
    <param name="file_path" value="beans.xml"/>
    <param name="item.path" value="/beans/bean[@id='classA']"/>
    <param name="item.name.path" value="class"/>
    <param name="item.name.value" value="a.b.c.d.classB"/>
</antcall>
```

Above approach is somehow not working, may be missing something. So, what changes can we do?

Comment: "We are importing this configuration in another project" - The another project is also a spring project? Can you access ApplicationContext?

Comment: Yes, I can access

Comment: then why not send the class name in the command line argument or pick it from env variable and change the class attribute after container startup.

Comment: the project is very huge. we don' know where and how this beans configuration is getting called in other modules. For us, safer way is to do with ant calls